# Datatables with php table

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I have tried this before with a different database and worked well, but with this database it's not working. I have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">

    <title>DataTables example - Zero configuration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dt/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dt/shCore.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dt/demo.css">
    <style type="text/css" class="init">

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dt/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dt/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dt/shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dt/demo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">







$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );


    </script>
</head>

<body>



<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Shopfloor</th>
                        <th>Cell</th>
                        <th>Line</th>
                        <th>Machine Section</th>
                        <th>Station</th>
                        <th>Technician</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Intervention</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Shopfloor</th>
                        <th>Cell</th>
                        <th>Line</th>
                        <th>Machine Section</th>
                        <th>Station</th>
                        <th>Technician</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Intervention</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>

                <tbody>


<?php
 $con = mysql_connect("10.1.68.12","xxxxx","xxxx");
mysql_select_db("tpm", $con);



$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM dbo_shopfloorcells INNER JOIN (dbo_noted_by INNER JOIN (dbo_leader_name INNER JOIN (dbo_Station INNER JOIN (dbo_Shop_Floor INNER JOIN (dbo_Fault_Desc INNER JOIN 
(dbo_Machine INNER JOIN (dbo_Line_Cell_Binding INNER JOIN (dbo_Tech_Name INNER JOIN (dbo_Maint_Category INNER JOIN dbo_newprevlog2 ON dbo_Maint_Category.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Maint_Cat) 
ON dbo_Tech_Name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name) ON dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Line_Desc) ON dbo_Machine.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Mach_Desc) 
ON dbo_Fault_Desc.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Fault_Desc) ON dbo_Shop_Floor.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor) ON dbo_Station.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Station_No) 
ON dbo_leader_name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Leader_Name) ON dbo_noted_by.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Noted_By) ON (dbo_shopfloorcells.PKID = dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor) 
AND (dbo_shopfloorcells.ID_Shop_Floor = dbo_Shop_Floor.ID)GROUP BY dbo_newprevlog2.ID, dbo_newprevlog2.Status, dbo_Shop_Floor.Shopfloor, dbo_shopfloorcells.Cell, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.Line_Name, 
dbo_Machine.Machine_Section, dbo_Station.Station_, dbo_Tech_Name.Technician_Name, dbo_Maint_Category.Maintenance_Category, dbo_Fault_Desc.Fault_Description, 
dbo_newprevlog2.Intervention, dbo_newprevlog2.Remarks, dbo_newprevlog2.ComponentsParts, dbo_newprevlog2.StartDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.EndDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.StartTime1, 
dbo_newprevlog2.EndTime1, dbo_newprevlog2.DurationTime, dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['Shopfloor'] . "</td>";  
  echo "<td>" . $row['Cell'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Line_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Machine_Section'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Station'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Technician_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StartDate1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['StartTime1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Intervention'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";


}

mysql_close($con);
?>  
</tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>


</body>

</html>
```

For some reason the page does not display correctly and it does not show the results. The links are well referenced since I tried it with zero_configuration.html but the page displays the table layout with

> " . $row['Shopfloor'] . " " . $row['Cell'] . "    " . $row['Line_Name'] .
>   " " . $row['Machine_Section'] . " " . $row['Station'] . " " .
>   $row['Technician_Name'] . "   " . $row['StartDate1'] . "

where supposed to be the results of the query. What am I missing please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elstiv, can you try with the code below. It will show you error if db is not connected or problem in query.

```
$con = mysql_connect("10.1.68.12","xxxxx","xxxx");
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("tpm",$con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo_shopfloorcells INNER JOIN (dbo_noted_by INNER JOIN (dbo_leader_name INNER JOIN (dbo_Station INNER JOIN (dbo_Shop_Floor INNER JOIN (dbo_Fault_Desc INNER JOIN 
(dbo_Machine INNER JOIN (dbo_Line_Cell_Binding INNER JOIN (dbo_Tech_Name INNER JOIN (dbo_Maint_Category INNER JOIN dbo_newprevlog2 ON dbo_Maint_Category.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Maint_Cat) 
ON dbo_Tech_Name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Tech_Name) ON dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Line_Desc) ON dbo_Machine.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Mach_Desc) 
ON dbo_Fault_Desc.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Fault_Desc) ON dbo_Shop_Floor.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor) ON dbo_Station.PKID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Station_No) 
ON dbo_leader_name.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Leader_Name) ON dbo_noted_by.ID = dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Noted_By) ON (dbo_shopfloorcells.PKID = dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor) 
AND (dbo_shopfloorcells.ID_Shop_Floor = dbo_Shop_Floor.ID)GROUP BY dbo_newprevlog2.ID, dbo_newprevlog2.Status, dbo_Shop_Floor.Shopfloor, dbo_shopfloorcells.Cell, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.Line_Name, 
dbo_Machine.Machine_Section, dbo_Station.Station_, dbo_Tech_Name.Technician_Name, dbo_Maint_Category.Maintenance_Category, dbo_Fault_Desc.Fault_Description, 
dbo_newprevlog2.Intervention, dbo_newprevlog2.Remarks, dbo_newprevlog2.ComponentsParts, dbo_newprevlog2.StartDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.EndDate1, dbo_newprevlog2.StartTime1, 
dbo_newprevlog2.EndTime1, dbo_newprevlog2.DurationTime, dbo_newprevlog2.ID_Shop_Floor, dbo_Line_Cell_Binding.ID_Cell_Shop_Floor";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row['Shopfloor'];

}
```

it's would be better to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` because `mysqli` is the future ready....

Comment: Thanks, the funny details have now disappeared but the table is showing 'No data available in table.' Very strange because I tested the SQL query and it works...

Comment: Do you think i ought to change the extension of the file from html to php? wold that make a difference?

Comment: yes, you need to change the extension html to php to run php code.